# Android: Access http server instead of https in vector (Android Matrix client)

Tags: android, http, https, sdk

- I'm using vector (It's a Android Matrix client Download link:
  https://github.com/vector-im/vector-android). This Vector is using
  the https server (https://vector.im and https://matrix.org as home
  and  identity url's) but i want to connect my local matrix server
  using http not https.
- For this i edited the strings.xml (id's are `vector_im_server_url,
  matrix_org_server_url, default_hs_server_url,
  default_identity_server_url`) file with my local http server.
- In this case i'm getting the toast message as "Unable to login :
  failed to connect to XXXXXX.XXXXXX.com/XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX (port 8008)
  after 15000ms". can anyone help where to change this setting

**Note:**

Initially i'm not able to access the local matrix server url in my system browser for this i added server details in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` after that i'm able to access it in my browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using **https server** only we can use vector services. So, i changed strings.xml as like this

```
<string name="vector_im_server_url">https://matrix.org</string>
<string name="matrix_org_server_url">my_local_https_server_url</string>
<string name="default_hs_server_url">my_local_https_server_url</string>
<string name="default_identity_server_url">https://matrix.org</string>
```

to know these url's open your local https server url in browser. It will show Home Server and Identity Server as shown in the image and paste **Identity Server url in vector_im_server_url and default_identity_server_url** then **Home Server url in matrix_org_server_url and default_hs_server_url**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think you missed my answer on #matrix:matrix.org. I tried to connect to your homeserver on port 8448 and 8008 from the public internet and the server was not responding. It looks like you need to open up your firewall on those ports. Please try asking again in #matrix:matrix.org (bearing in mind that the core matrix team are awake on european timezones).

Edit: As per https://vector.im/develop/#/room/#matrix:matrix.org/$147222237811409Apqfi:matrix.org, the server really was inaccessible when we tried to give you support earlier.  Glad you've got it sorted now; you should also be using the same HS url for both 'vector' and 'matrix' HS URL otherwise it will try to fall back to using matrix.org for unrecognised users.  Thanks for the downvote...

M

Comment: Hi Matthew thank you for your support. You gave lot of support in vector room and also in StackOverflow. Because of you and other people's thoughts in vector room only i got the solution. So i'm posting the answer here, if any vector user faces the same problem means kindly update them. Thank you for your support matthew